# Indexing files using Lucene

Tags: java, apache, search, lucene, indexing

I have a set of files with different extensions .doc .txt .html etc.

How do I index these files to use with Apache Lucene?

Comment: Did you read any of the available documentation, tutorials and/or getting started guides? What do you have already? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Can you add more details of your implementation?   Are you having issues with a current implementation?  Are you planning a new implementation where you need to index certain files?    Please add more details so others know the context of your problem

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html

Comment: I  dont have any code, just looking at the above links, its quite overwhelming for me as i am quite new to programming.

Comment: @james: you have the docs. Read them. If you get stuck on a _specific_ issue, ask a question about that.

Comment: ok lets forget about this for a minute, how do i search for these docs  if i have a query box, and search .doc, to get all the .doc files. Can you please provide me some links. This may sound really stupid because i should be doing this myself but i dnt know what i need, a Google search will return thousands if not millions of results, i dont know what i am looking for , so its rather difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library to extract text from them first and then index them using the code availabel here : 
[Apache Lucene-Use lucene 3.4.0 to index text files](http://computergodzilla.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Lucene is not too easy to get started. Maybe is an overkill to read a book, but I started using Lucene reading a few chapters from [Lucene in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394281).

Comment: Is there a book for Lucene 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

For indexing rich documents you would need a combination of Apache Lucene and [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/).
If you are using lucene, you would need to parse the files using Tika libraries and pass the content to lucene for indexing.

Apache Tika allows easy apis for extraction, doing the work of detection of the files types and retrieving content and other attributes from the files.

You should find [example](http://johnreece.com/wordpress/2011/03/13/a-concise-tikalucene-content-parsing-and-indexing-example/) on these.

Answer (score 0):

You use something like Apache Tika to extract text from them. You might find it easier to start with Apache Solr instead of raw lucene.